# Do we have a way to read NVMe driver's completion queue entry via nvmecli?

Tags: linux-device-driver, device-driver, nvme

Do we have a way to read NVMe device's completion queue entry using nvme cli ?

Here are steps done using nvme cli, version 1.6 & 1.9
*shell> sudo nvme id-ctrl /dev/nvme0*
...
...
This provides the nvme identify ctrl information for the selected device as per ask.

From the nvmecli command line options, not finding options to read the nvme device's completion queue entry for the last nvme command posted.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/linux-nvme/nvme-cli/issues/858

Got answers from another forum. Hence arking this as closed.